# Implement facebook pixel flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-pixel

I am trying to integrate Facebook pixel in my ecommerce flutter app to show ads according to customers search behavior but could not get any documentation or library for flutter. How can I integrate facbook pixel in  Flutter app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Facebook Pixel is strictly for webapps, but for native app development, Facebook SDK is required.

[Flutter Facebook Login Package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_login) will provide you, not only the login but also the required SDK.

Next up, you probably want [Facebook_App_Events Package](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events), which is going to help you in sending tracked data to FB, for eg. when a person clicks to watch a video on your app or makes a purchase etc.

> An app event is an action that takes place in your app or on your web page such as a person installing your app or completing a purchase. Facebook App Events allows you to track these events to view analytics, measure ad performance, and build audiences for ad targeting.

Comment: do we need both plugin ?