# How to integrate Facebook Pixel Sdk in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, facebook-pixel, flutter2.0

I want to integrate the facebook pixel sdk in flutter. Can anyone help me that how i can integrate that in my flutter project

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement facebook pixel flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66776416/implement-facebook-pixel-flutter)

Comment: @RobertSandberg i didn't want to show ads i just want to integrate pixel sdk to check how many user came from ads

Answer (score 2):

For native app development, [Facebook SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_sdk) is required.

[Flutter Facebook Login](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_login_facebook) Package will provide you, not only the login but also the required SDK.

Next, [Facebook_App_Events](https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events) Package, which is going to help you in sending tracked data to FB, for eg. when a person clicks to watch a video on your app or makes a purchase etc.

> An app event is an action that takes place in your app or on your web
> page such as a person installing your app or completing a purchase.
> Facebook App Events allows you to track these events to view
> analytics, measure ad performance, and build audiences for ad
> targeting.